# cv_bridge installation in windows10 for ROS2

Tags: ros2, cv-bridge, windows10

I need cv_bridge to run a publisher node in windows.
I have installed ROS2(humble) and all other dependencies...

I had installed opencv also..

After downloading and extracting cv_bridge from https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv

When i tried to build it,it shows some error...

Starting >>> cv_bridge
--- stderr: cv_bridge
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2392 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)

---

Failed   <<< cv_bridge [3.84s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [4.48s]
1 package failed: cv_bridge
1 package had stderr output: cv_bridge
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

C:\vision_opencv-humble\vision_opencv-humble\cv_bridge>sudo apt install python3-numpy
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I had even installed boost version....